# How to align the button horizontally and vertically in Document?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I want to align the button horizontally and vertically in Document, i now ho to align horizontally, but i can`t undestand how to align vertically?

In picture bellow, button align horizontal, but how align vertically, in option button i don`t find something about align vertically.

[image: option button]

[image: align horizontally]

Answer (score 1):

Vertical align is possible in tables only.

[image]
Create a table with one row and one column. Set wanted height as "Minimum height" and "Vertically align" to "Center". Content will be centered vertically this way.

I know, it is just a workaround, but it works. Of course, set "Cell Border Thickness" all to 0 so table border is invisible.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but how i can create table what will be fit not just horizontal, how i now "Fit tot window" it only about  horizontal size.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to get the same functionality of "fit to window" for vertical direction. That's why I called it a workaround and not a solution... The approach above is useful in cases of content with different hide-when-formulas: this way the content is always centered vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If those are 2 buttons, why don’t you just put a ‘return’ (CR) between them. The 2 buttons will be positioned one below the other.
If need be, you can size the buttons, so they have the same width via the properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to "fit to window" vertically in normaal Notes form and document display. It assumes an infinitely long document consisting of paragraphs.

There is, however, the option of displaying a document using the [@DialogBox](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/1902c00cf58904f885256c54004bfd32?OpenDocument) formula or the [NotesUIWorkpace.DialogBox](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX_METHOD.html) method. Both of those have an auto vertical fit argument that you can provide. This will likely require you to redesign your application a bit, but I think it's the only way to do what you want.